# Calling web-app methods using hessdroid = new AsyncTask for each method?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, hessian

In my Android application I want to call some web-app methods.
I use hessian for this (hessdroid library for Android).

That's how it works:
In my Android app I have interfaces for all of the the server methods e.g. getUserById(), getMessageById(), getSomethingElse() etc.

With Hessian I can call these methods through http.

So I need to initalize Hessian Proxy for that:

```
HessianProxyFactory proxyFactory = new HessianProxyFactory();
UserAccountService api = (UserAccountService) proxyFactory.create(UserAccountService.class, "http://localhost:8080/server/UserAccountService", getClassLoader());
```

After that I am able to run server methods like that:

```
UserAccount user = api.getUserById(999);
```

The problem is that api calls like "api.someMethod();" require running from separeted thread. In any other case I have NetworkOnMainThread exception.

My question is about how to make these calls in right way?
Should I create AsyncTask for every server method call? Or it is possible to make that more generic? I really dont think that creating AsyncTask for every method is a right way. It makes code dirty.

Any ideas? I really appreciate any solution you can provide.